# Using empty to properly rotate object

Tags: animation, armature, bones, empty

[image]When rotating empty (empty from the left is tracked to the one on the right) the rotation doesn't look as I wanted. I want to achieve the result shown in the second part of the clip I attached (with the red in front). Tried with bones and the result was the same. Empty from the right is parent of the object, and I want to rotate the object by changing the location of empty from the left, would be great if the one from the left would also rotating to the center as at the start of the animation, and by rotating left empty i would also rotate the object, all of this is a part of hand animation where i want to grab the end of the hand and be able to move the whole hand and rotate it by the help of single empty/bone.

**EDIT:**

I will try to explain it more sensibly. I want to create a mechanism whereby I can move my hand by just catching it by the empty on the "palm". The arm will always remain in the same place. I would also like to be able to rotate the whole hand by rotating only the empty on the palm. The problem is (you can see it in the attached gif) that the hand/object does not make perfect rotations, but at some point it "wraps". When I make the rotation by rotating the arm (further down in the gif) the hand rotates as I would like, but I want to achieve this by catching the empty on "palm".

File: [image]

Comment: What rotation method are you using on your central empty (XYZ Euler, Quternion etc.)? Looks to me as if playing with these may fix this.

Comment: I tried some options (on both empty and object) but the result was the same every time :/

Comment: Hello, Lopli.. I can't be sure of your desired workflow, but I think this question might be a bit [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a,(Y%20or%20Why%3F).)  .Your edit expresses the particular problem very nicely.. maybe better to leave it at that, rather than restrict the range of possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

you know i just realized the two empties could not be in perfect flush with eachother.  setting the x and y to 0 and having the z be the only difference might to the trick.

or just simplify it to one empty.  no one will see the empties in the final product after all.

Comment: The one empty need to hold the arm in one position. The other one (palm) is to move the hand where I want to. By steering the hand with the help of the arm I will not be able to hold the palm in one position while the rest of the body will be moving moving because the arm should be attached to the shoulder/body. IDK how else I would simplify it to one empty :/

Comment: I want to be able to easily make animations like, for example, someone going down the stairs grasping the handrail without worrying about the correct placement of the hand every frame, thanks to the hand control once I set the empty on the handrail and it will stay there even as the rest of the body moves.

Answer (score -1):

under object properties there is a a little lock.  click it.  i'd lock the axis you are not using.

that should get rid of the wraps of the wrong axis

Comment: I am rotating by moving object, locking rotation does not affect this. Also, when I am moving not exactly by axis I am using every 3 axis at the same time, so locking even if worked, would not be the solution (unless I misunderstood something and you mean some other option to lock rotation that I don't know about).

Comment: maybe then the empties aren't in perfect flush to each other.